# Django Rest Framework: AttributeError when Serializer many=False, but not when many=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `Slide` and `Chart` models, and slides can contain only 1 chart. When serializing the data it fails with the below error:

**AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `csv` on serializer `ChartSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'csv'.**

However, if I simply change:

```
chart = ChartSerializer(many=True)
```

in my `SlideSerializer`  (code below) it works.  This makes the 'chart' property a list in JSON though when it should be an object as there can only be one Chart, not many (or in this case one) chart objects in a list.

Here are my models (extracts of relevant info only):

```
# models.py

...

class Slide(models.Model):
    TYPE_MEDIA = 'media'
    TYPE_CHART = 'chart'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (TYPE_MEDIA, 'Media'),
        (TYPE_CHART, 'Chart'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=5, default=TYPE_MEDIA)

    media = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='media',
        upload_to='slides',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    internal_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Chart(models.Model):
    slide = models.ForeignKey(Slide, related_name='chart')

    csv = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='csv',
        upload_to='charts'
    )

    vertical_label = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    horizontal_label = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ChartSeriesLabel(models.Model):
    """Series label associated with a chart"""

    chart = models.ForeignKey(Chart, related_name='serieslabels')

    number = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ChartDataLabel(models.Model):
    """Data label associated with a chart"""

    chart = models.ForeignKey(Chart, related_name='datalabels')

    date = models.DateField()
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And my serializers:

```
# serializers.py

...

class SeriesLabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChartSeriesLabel
        fields = ('number', 'label',)


class DataLabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChartDataLabel
        fields = ('date', 'label',)


class ChartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serieslabels = SeriesLabelSerializer(many=True)
    datalabels = DataLabelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chart
        fields = ('csv', 'vertical_label', 'horizontal_label', 'serieslabels', 'datalabels')


class SlideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chart = ChartSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Slide
        fields = ('title', 'type', 'media', 'chart')
```

Output with `chart = ChartSerializer(many=True)` in `SlideSerializer`:

```
...

{
    "title": "Slide 3",
    "type": "chart",
    "media": null,
    "chart": [
        {
            "csv": "/media/commodities/Hall_of_Fame_Inductees.csv",
            "vertical_label": "Vert",
            "horizontal_label": "Horiz",
            "serieslabels": [
                {
                    "number": "1",
                    "label": "One"
                },
                {
                    "number": "2",
                    "label": "Two"
                },
                {
                    "number": "3",
                    "label": "Three"
                }
            ],
            "datalabels": [
                {
                    "date": "2015-07-22",
                    "label": "This"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2015-07-23",
                    "label": "That"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2015-07-31",
                    "label": "The other"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

...
```

> Note that `chart` is a JSON list indicating that it could be many charts

Expected output with `chart = ChartSerializer()` in `SlideSerializer`:

```
...

{
    "title": "Slide 3",
    "type": "chart",
    "media": null,
    "chart": {
        "csv": "/media/commodities/Hall_of_Fame_Inductees.csv",
        "vertical_label": "Vert",
        "horizontal_label": "Horiz",
        "serieslabels": [
            {
                "number": "1",
                "label": "One"
            },
            {
                "number": "2",
                "label": "Two"
            },
            {
                "number": "3",
                "label": "Three"
            }
        ],
        "datalabels": [
            {
                "date": "2015-07-22",
                "label": "This"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015-07-23",
                "label": "That"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015-07-31",
                "label": "The other"
            }
        ]
    }
},

...
```

But instead it throws the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you written is working fine. Dealing with nested representation should be a list of items, you should pass the `many=True` flag to the nested serializers. Visit
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

So you need to pass:

```
chart = ChartSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: I understand that, however, as I mentioned there is only 1 chart associated with a slide.  So `many=True` does not make sense.  The chart property should be represented as an object, not a list.  A list would be for "many" charts, and object for one chart.

Comment: @tsantor In your models slide has FK relation in chart model. If we look at reverse relation one slide will have many chart. So we need to pass many=True to chartserializer.

Comment: Perhaps it's my confusion.  To me a FK the the Chart model means the Chart belongs to a (one) Slide.  It's not a Many to Many field.  Would it be better to use a OneToOne Field to get an single object (and not a list) returned?

Comment: See according to you model FK relation you need to pass the many=True in the serializers. If you want single object it would be better if you use OneTone Field in the models.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it returns a list of one object even I wrote many=False. I think the reason is that child objects are accessed through filter() query. Thus it uses many=True by default

---

I solved it by using the SerializerMethodField.

For example:

```
class SlideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chart = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Slide
        fields = ('title', 'type', 'media', 'chart')
    def get_chart(self, obj):
        return ChartSerializer(obj.chart).data
```